# pause the current thread on execution in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I obtain a request message from a HTML web page perfom some pre processing and send the response to the ui.

within a case statement the code is as follows:

```
reqClientName= request.getParameter("clientname");
System.out.println(" agent"+clientName);
reqMessage = request.getParameter("message");
System.out.println(" message"+message);             
jaf.initiateRequest(clientName,message);
response.getWriter().println("Message Processed at Server (Echo Response)   is"+getResponseMessage());
```

here `jaf.initiateRequest` takes some time to execute and even before the execution is completed the `response.getWriter.println()` gets executed and this is empty.

Is there a thread safe method of getting this done ?

Comment: What are `jaf` and `getResponseMessage`?

Comment: @assylias jaf is a object calling a method which performs some processing and sets a String responseMessage, I am trying to access this string using the getter here

Comment: You need to make either `initiateRequest` or `getResponseMessage` a blocking call. More likely `getResponseMessage`. So whatever you are doing asynchronously, you need to wait for completion in that method before it returns.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `CountDownLatch`, from concurrent package. Its thread safe. This will give you an opportunity to do the processing work, and once its done, execute the goal.

Comment: count down latch is really interesting but I am really not sure how long i need to count down, i do not want to hard code a value.

Comment: @bhavs The idea is to trigger the latch once the response has been received.